# Handsontable how to use 'deselectCell()'

Tags: javascript, handsontable

with Handsontable 0.26.1 after change of a value in `table1` I will switch to `table2` and get `TypeError: priv.selRange is null`

```js
var container = document.getElementById('table1');
var table1 = new Handsontable(container, {
  afterChange: function (changes,source) {
    if (changes[0][2] !== changes[0][3]) {
      //this.getActiveEditor().finishEditing();  // didn't help
      //this.getActiveEditor().close();          // didn't help
      this.deselectCell();
      table2.selectCell(0,0);
    }
  },
  columns: [
    {title: 'column1'},
    {title: 'column2'},
    {title: 'column3'}
  ]
});
```

As I didn't find a similar problem in the web, I think, the failure is between my ears. What is wrong with my advisement? A fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/steloh/3u809v02/).. After a input in table1, you can't navigate with the arrow-keys in table2.

EDIT:
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/steloh/71pncd27/) is a – humpy – workaround.

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @Santhucool I made my fist fiddle :) The error in the fiddle – `TypeError: c.selRange is null` – is different to my local error `TypeError: priv.selRange is null`. Maybe because different HOT-scripts? I add the link to my first post.